# WiFi Intel AX210NGW cannot work under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, kernel

I have installed a new wifi adapter (Intel AX210NGW) on a Dell Latitude E5470 laptop, running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, Kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic, but the system does not recognize it ("WiFi adapter not found").

Although the driver provided by Intel’s official website indicated that the network card requires Kernel 5.10+, I also noticed someone mentioning that AX210 can be installed in Ubuntu 16.04 and used normally. Through `lspci`, the hardware of the network card can be shown correctly. Is there any way to use AX210 network card under 16.04.3 with kernel 4.10?

Comment: Since 16.04 is EOL in April I would suggest you upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04 that may fix the issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 ships with a v5.3 based Linux kernel updated from the v5.0 based kernel in 18.04.3. This enables the latest hardware and peripherals available from IBM, Intel, and others.12 Aug 2020

Comment: The only way that you will be able to use the AX210 on a 4.10 kernel is to get the drivers and compile them yourself. This may require you to drastically modify your system as there will be dependencies for newer versions of network libraries and the like. If you're willing to take complete control over your kernel, you can certainly do it ... but it's a remarkable amount of work.

Comment: Okay, I will try to reinstall 18.04.4. It’s very complicated to use the AX210 on a 4.10 kernel, I decided to give up 16.04.3.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install an updated linux kernel version (v5.11).
On Ubuntu (I'm not sure if 16.04 support this version) you can install mainline to manage and install an updated kernel version. Then restart and you wifi card will works.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Comment: OP may as well just upgrade to 18.04 and then 20.04 - 16.04 reaches the end of standard support in just over a month.